# Sooner/earlier-interchangeability

Tags: synonyms

He arrived at the party **sooner/earlier** than I expected.

He should have rectified his mistakes **sooner/earlier**.

In cases like these, **sooner** and **earlier** act as synonyms, and the overall meaning is not affected by whichever is used, right?

Answer (score 0):

In those two sentences, they are very close. In more general use, "sooner" suggests an arbitrary reference, and "earlier" suggests an external, absolute reference.

Taking your first example,
I expected him to take an hour to get here. He arrived in 45 minutes, **sooner** than I expected.
I expected him at eight o'clock. He he got here at 7:30, **earlier** than I expected.

Looking at your second example,
His mistakes were pointed out, and it took him a long time to fix them. He should have corrected them **sooner.**

His mistakes could not be corrected because the final edits have been done. 
 He should have corrected them **earlier** in the process.

(In the first example, I wouldn't call it an error if the words were switched; it's a subtle difference.)

Answer (score 0):

Typical usage has "sooner" used when referencing a time in the relative past:

> The test started only 30 minutes ago and he's finished sooner than I would have thought possible.

In contrast, "earlier" is typically used in reference to a time in the relative future:

> The test was scheduled to end in another 2 hours, but he finished earlier than I would have thought possible.

These are **NOT** hard rules, just typical usage.